# ServiceStack - Simulating a stronger Scope for IRequestLogger

Tags: servicestack

This is not a question about the RequestLogsService or the RequestLogFeature. It is about the ServiceRunner's call to a IRequestLogger (if one is registered at the app container).

My app has regular logging in place, I dump the app's flow to log a file.

I am now implementing a database log, inspired by the RequestLogsService. This log will contain one line per request, containing all the Request and Response data.

However my endpoint produces outputs at 4 different levels:

- Custom auth filter
- Validation
- Service
- AppHostExceptionHandler

From those 4, only the Service outputs are covered by the IRequestLogger, because its ServiceRunner related. Is there any way I can cover my 4 scenarios transparently? I want to minimize the complexity introduced in the pipeline.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I encountered a similar problem recently and resolved it as follows:

**Custom Auth filter**

There are 2 possibilities with this one based upon the type of logging you would like. If you throw an exception in here, you can catch it by setting up an `ServiceExceptionHandler` in AppHost:

```
this.ServiceExceptionHandler = (httpRequest, request, exception) =>
{
    LogData(httpRequest, exception);
    return DtoUtils.HandleException(this, request, exception);
};
```

If that approach won't work for you or you don't throw an exception during auth, you will have to instead create a logging filter either before or after the auth filter is run. This can be done in a few different locations using either a `PreRequestFilter` or a `RequestFilter` depending on when exactly you need it to run (see ServiceStack's [Order of Operations](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Order-of-Operations)).

**Validation**

I'll assume you are using ServiceStack's built in `FluentValidation` to perform your validation. In this case, you can hook into the plugin's `ErrorResponseFilter` like so. Note that if you require the IHttpRequest and IHTTPresponse objects in this method, you may have to do a hack-y workaround and stash them somewhere as they aren't supplied.:

```
Plugins.Add(new ValidationFeature { ErrorResponseFilter = ValidationErrorResponseFilter});
...
private object ValidationError(ValidationResult validationResult, object o)
{
    var httpError = o as HttpError;
    LogData(httpError);
}
```

**AppHostExceptionHandler**

If the exception occurs in setup of the AppHost, you may have to settle with a simple try/catch. If the exception occurs in AppHost during the request processing however, you can use the `ExceptionHandler` similar to the `ServiceExceptionHandler` above:

```
this.ExceptionHandler = (httpReq, httpRes, operationName, ex) =>
{
    LogData(httpReq, httpRes);
}
```

**In conclusion**, if all of this doesn't work or is too much code in too many places, you can instead resort to overriding one or more methods in `ServiceRunner` to get what you need. In my case I overrode `OnAfterExecute` to log every request that made it to the service handler and then only had to add the exception handler to `FluentValidation` as noted above.